# Encoding problems while displaying formatted text with php

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have formatted english text stored in mysql. When I echo it out with php, I get a whole a lot of "� � � � � ���" instead of where spaces should be. It looks fine in the DB.

Whats the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across this problem before and what I have done is set the db and column collation to *utf8_general_ci*.
And between my  tags put the below meta line in.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Then I ran this query when I open my db connection: `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

This helped me with multilingual websites quite a bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

That will most likely have to do with either your database has a conflicting character set to that of your html document, or your server is pushing out the wrong character encoding for your html document.

Comment: The most insane thing is that it outputs the text just fine in one php file, and not in another.

Comment: what is your mysql Collation set to?

Comment: utf8_general_ci for that particular column.

Answer (score 0):

if your characters looks OK in your DB:
Try setting this php/html output-encode  to the same encode you have in your DB...

What characters are? speaking language?...

Comment: Yes, it looks okay. Its in English.